# Automatically execute a command when opening a command group?

Tags: conemu

I use the following command daily for debugging:

```
adb logcat -s Unity | findstr /c:"[U]" /c:"[W]" /c:"[D]"
```

I love ConEmu, but I'm having trouble understanding some of the "Predefined Task" functionality.  How can I launch a new console tab that automatically executes the command above?  Here is what I tried, but it does not work:

[image]

This results in the following output:

> ```
> Invalid filter expression '/c:[U]'
> Usage: logcat [options] [filterspecs]
> options include:
> <remainder of help file>
> ```

Looks like it might be something to do with the quotes?  Do I need to escape them somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ConEmu does not support pipelines itself. If you want to run such conveyers you shall use `cmd /c ...` or `bash -c`.

```
cmd /c "adb logcat -s Unity | findstr /c:"[U]" /c:"[W]" /c:"[D]""
```